# Only load JS file once with EJS and res.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a Node.js SPA with a lot of global variables and calculations inside a JS file, and I used to serve the website like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

One single HTML file with the JS file loading once and when users clicked on the menu I used HTML templates and JS to re-render the view, meaning the global objects storing all the data was always available.

However now I wanted to add routing so people can visit /about etc, so I'm using EJS to render the pages, only problem is the JS file is loaded every time whenever a user clicks on a menu item since the file is included in the script tag of the EJS pages. It really slows down the website.

app.js:

```
router.get("/", function(req,res,next) {
    res.render("index", { page: "home" });
});

router.get("/about", function(req,res,next) {
    res.render("about", { page: "about" });
});
```

index.ejs:

```
...
<% include partials/scripts %>
</body>
</html>
```

scripts.ejs:

```
...
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
let WebApp = (function() {
    // global variables here
    ...

    return {
        init: function() {
            // init and calculate variables here
            // display view depending on variables
        }
    };
})();
window.onload = WebApp.init();
```

Is there any way to easily prevent this from happening or do I need to restructure my site?

Comment: the code snippet u provided doesn't remotely relate to your problem. Please post the relevant code so that we can help you.

Comment: ok I updated it with more code. Note that I'm not using any client side web frameworks, it's all vanilla HTML and JS with Node.js on the server.